# Transforming a circle into a sphere by z-axis inflation

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

This question is somehow an analogue to the mylar balloons or paper bag problem, but I was unable to find a solution for the surface of the latter cases (the focus is usually on the calculation of the volume).

If transforming a circle into a sphere along with $z$-axis, we can calculate the $z$ for each given $x,y$ point by

$$(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 + (z-z_0)^2 = r^2$$

assuming the circle is centered in the $x-y$ plane:

$$z = \sqrt{r^2-x^2-y^2}$$

Now if applying a condition for the inflation process. For example, $z$ remains $0$ at $x,y=0,0$ (the circle centre), which creates a torus.

[image]

How can we generally calculate the $z$ for a given point $x,y$?

The key point in the sphere case is that $z=0$ at the circle edge, and $z=r$ at $0,0$.

How do we apply the conditions in a typical case like the torus case given above (not generally solving torus)?

Comment: You have a more fundamental problem already in the previous question. You thought a rectangle would "inflate" into a cylinder, but the circular ends of the cylinder would violate the requirement that $z=0$ along the boundary, just as a sphere in this example would violate the constraint that $z=0$ at $(x,y)=(0,0).$

Comment: @DavidK that was just clumsy terminology. I meant cylinder with round ends (spheres). I was referring to uniform inflation over the body of the cylinder.

Comment: That doesn't work either, because spheres don't fill out the corners of the original rectangle -- unless you let them expand horizontally as well as vertically so that the rectangle's edge becomes a diameter of the sphere.

Comment: @DavidK you're right, the ends will be rounded but not a sphere. the rectangle edges will be driven into the cylinder to form the round ends.

Comment: @DavidK technically, the inflation is possible/allowed horizontally too (my mistake) as it is physical pressure indeed.

Comment: If the center of the sphere is at (0,0,0) - the simple equation will determine the inflation as function of $r$ - $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$.

Comment: @Moti that's the equation of torus (with $R_{small}=0$). We need a general solution, not the special case given for demonstration.

Comment: What you mean by general? Always a sphere? Center moving from (0,0,0)? Is your problem with the tours that r=0 at (0,0,0)?

Comment: @Moti It is not about torus at all. This is a case of $z=0$ at $x,y=0,0$, which creates a torus. Another case is $z=0$ at $x,y=1,1$. This is always the transformation of a circle to a sphere, but we hold a point at the $x-y$ plane. Imagine inflating a ball while we hold a point to the ground by a finger.

Comment: What is the starting state? Do you start with a ball and than press one point inside? I am not sure you explain your problem right when you define it as an inflation. May be you want to say you start with a ball and than you pick a cord and squeeze it into a point on the x,y plane. In your case the cord assumed to be perpendicular to the x,y plane.

Comment: @Moti it doesn't matter where we start, I look for the relationship of 3D and 2D objects. Imagine an empty ball (which is a circle). We put two strong magnets on both sides of the circle at the centre. Then, we blow into the ball, which forms a torus instead of a sphere. We have the torus equation for the 3D object. Now move the magnets away from the centre. How do you predict the $z$ coordinates of the 3D object?

Comment: If you have the ball and place the magnet, you mean their attraction causes the ball to become a torus (why there is a need to blow?). Your explanation seems like taking a ball, selecting a vertical cord - place the magnets at the edges of the cord to get a distorted torus. Is your question what equation describes this distorted torus?

Comment: @Moti you can interpret it that way. What's the relationship between the distorted torus/sphere and the 2D circle according to the place of the magnet? Or how do we predict the shape ($z$ values) of the distorted torus/sphere for a given place of the magnet?

Comment: This is actually a PHYSICS problem. You need to assume some tension force for the inflated surface. You solve the differential equation you get - may be it is not depended of the tension if you assume homogeneity over the surface.